# Symfony2 on Mac OS no background-images found

Tags: css, macos, symfony

My CSS is being linked like this:

```
{% stylesheets '@MyFrontendBundle/Resources/public/css/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

The background-images in this CSS-file:

```
#pic     {background-image:url('../../bundles/myfrontend/images/pic.png');}
```

Both the CSS and the Image-Folders are in the Resources/public/.
The background images just won't show. When I look for the path in the browser, it shows

```
background-image:url('../../Resources/bundles/myfrontend/images/pic.png');
```

Why does it add Resources to my path? If I edit the path in the Firebug back to

```
background-image:url('../../bundles/myfrontend/images/pic.png');
```

the background is being shown.

I hope, someone can help me out with this.

P.S.: The problem doesn't exist on Linux. The background-images are being shown there.

Comment: Have you tried to install asset?
php app/console asset:install --symlink

Comment: Yes, I tried both asset:install and assetic:dump :/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
{% stylesheets '@MyFrontendBundle/Resources/public/css/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

Edit:

```
background-image:url('../../../bundles/myfrontend/images/pic.png');
```

Comment: I tried this, but I get an exception: An exception has been thrown during the compilation of a template ("Unable to find file "@MyFrontendBundle/public/css/".") in MyFrontendBundle:Default:index.html.twig at line 1.

Comment: Try this:
background-image:url('../../../bundles/myfrontend/images/pic.png');
with {% stylesheets '@MyFrontendBundle/Resources/public/css/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}